# What chord is G-C#-E in a D minor context?

Tags: theory

I’m looking at a score notated in D minor. The first measures are evidently in D minor, followed by a F-A-D (Ic - second inversion). But the next measure has a G-C#-E.

I know that D harmonic minor has a C# but my search of chords based on those notes shows nothing apparently related to D minor.

Comment: It's the diminished 7 chord, or 3 notes of an A7 chord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C♯ dim.  Very likely acting as an incomplete A7, the dominant 7th of D minor.

In this case, it does 'fit the scale'.   But chords that don't are allowed!

Answer (score 0):

The chord is a C# diminished triad in second inversion (viic).

Minor *keys* admit both the raised and lowered seventh (C# and C) as well as raised and lowered sixth (B and Bb).

Minor *scales* are representation of the various ways the raised and lowered intervals are used in compositions.

---

For more on the difference between *keys* and *scales* see, for example: [Difference between keys and scales?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/38939/70803)